# How to get iPhone name from osx terminal?

Tags: iphone, macos, shell, terminal, usb

I am writing a simple script to download photos from an iPhone and then copy them to my server. I'd like to find the name of the iPhone that I currently have plugged in. So when I save my pictures I can save them in a folder named "currentDate/Dave's iPhone", "currentDate/Other iPhone", etc.

Wondering if there is a way to get the connected device's name from terminal. Ie. when I look at my device in Xcode or Image Capture it says my device name is Dave's iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`libimobiledevice-macosx`](https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx) and its `ideviceinfo` utility:

```
$ ideviceinfo | grep -i DeviceName
```

If you get linker errors while running the executable, you may need to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to the path where you downloaded the library.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

use this command in terminal